# Connect home theater to laptop or mobile

Tags: sound, laptop, soundcard, home-theatre

I have a 5.1 home theater with the ports as the figure shows. How can I connect it to my laptop? [image]

Comment: I guess your laptop only has the top green headphone jack. So not directly with 5.1 sound. But it should work with an USB soundcard or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Check audio device 'Profiles:' on laptop with:

```
pactl list cards
```

This will show Pulseaudio options for stereo or surround sound

Unlikely a laptop will have option for analog surround sound

Many do not have 3 jack sockets to connect to the 3 sockets on speaker for 5.1 surround.

Digital (SPDIF or IEC958) surround sound may be possible through audio jack 

Check manual for speakers to see if they support digital input

Digital surround sound may only be possible using HDMI connection not audio jacks